# Determining clock frequency on FPGA Spartan-6

Tags: vhdl, clock, fpga, spartan

I'm working to learn how to program an FPGA in VHDL and want to know how I can determine the correct frequency of my clock input.

I have used the [Sp605 Hardware User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug526.pdf), pin K21 which in the Clock Source Connections table (pg 27 if you're interested!) is described as being "200 MHz OSC SYSCLK_P".

I then used the following process in order to try and create a 1 Hz clock from the 200 MHz clock

```
prescaler : process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if (counter < 1000000) then --possibly change to number in binary
            counter <= counter + 1;
        else
            CLK_1Hz <= not CLK_1Hz;
            counter <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

However, if I set the counter upper limit to be 100,000,000 - which it should be, the clock is far far slower than 1 Hz - in fact using the current value of 1,000,000 counts gives a close approximation of a 1 Hz pulse - but why is this?

Comment: Your code is counting for 100 Hz: the counter -> divide by 1,000,000 and the embedded T flipflop -> divide by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to say that you are currently using `K21 OSC SYSCLK_P` as a single-ended clock input and directly connected it to `CLK`.
Please include a snippet of your UCF file for reference in future questions.

This won't work, because the individual differential clock lines' peak-to-peak voltage will not reliably register as logical `0` or `1` respectively with a non-differential (`LVCMOS25`?) I/O standard.

You'll have to

- include both _P and _N ports on your entity,
- instantiate an LVDS buffer in your design, and
- connect _P and _N ports to the buffer in order to get `CLK` from the buffer's output `O`

Don't forget to change the I/O standard in your UCF file.